# Does 'a+' mode allow random access to files, on all systems?

Tags: python

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) of open function
'a' means appending, which on some Unix systems means that all writes append to the end of the file regardless of the current seek position.

Will 'a+' allow random writes to any position in the file on all systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my linux system with Python 2.5.2 writes to a file opened with 'a+' appear to always append to the end, regardless of the current seek position.

Here is an example:

```
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":

    f = open("test", "w")
    f.write("Hello")
    f.close()

    f = open("test", "a+")
    f.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
    f.write("Goodbye")
    f.close()
```

On my system (event though I seeked to the beginning of the file) this results in the file "test" containing:

> HelloGoodbye

The python documentation says that the mode argument is the same as stdio's.

The linux man page for [fopen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) does say that (emphasis added):

> Opening a file in append mode (a as
>   the **first character** of mode) causes
>   all subsequent write operations to
>   this stream to occur at end-of-file,
>   as if preceded by an
>
> ```
> fseek(stream,0,SEEK_END);
> ```
>
> call.

My stdio reference says that appending a '+' to the mode (i.e. 'a+') means that the stream is opened for *input and output*.  However before switching between input and output a call must be made to explicitly set the file position.

So adding the '+' doesn't change the fact that on some systems writes for a file opened in 'a' or 'a+' mode will always append to the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that I need to check if file exists and open with different file modes :(